# Java: allowed to add custom class to java.awt.image?

Tags: java, package

I'm pretty shure the answer is somewhere, but either im lacking the correct key-words or simply should get some sleep, but here it is ;~) :

I need to extend BufferedImage and the only way to do this w/o MacGyvering the whole class would be to let the new class rest in java.awt.image, because it contains a package-visible-only field i need to access. Normaly, there would be a reason to dont to such a thing, but if you check the source, you'll see that this is not true in this special case.

So I tested it, it compiles and it *seems* to run.

But can i rely on it? Is it allowed? Is there anything that could prevent me from adding classes to java's predefined system packages? Or is this simply the correct way to do it and no one told me?

**UPDATE**

The answeres already provided stated the possibility of legal concerns (if doing something *correctly* means breaking some laws than my default solution frequently is beeing uninterested in those laws;-) and the possibility of changed behaviour in the super-class (very unlikely in that case). If that's all, i'd just do it that way…

**UPDATE2**

Great! Java is a protected package name… So i really have to MacGyver this…

**UPDATE3**

I was just wondering why i cant get the property hash-keys. The fn getPropertyNames is documented just so: *Returns an array of names recognized by getProperty(String)*… let's look into the sourcecode:

```
public String[] getPropertyNames() {
     return null;
}
```

Best code i've ever read…

Comment: Extending a class does not depend on the package of the new class unless the class being extended is not `public`. `BufferedImage` is `public`. What are you doing? And why?

Comment: but BufferedImage.properties is not. It is simply package-visible :-@! And the only way to set this field from derived class is by one single constructor. But the other c-tor have very usefull functionality that i therefore cant use. The only way to overcome this is to let the derived class rest in the same package.

Comment: My first question is "what are you trying to do?" I've done a *lot* of image processing and I've never found a need to extend BufferedImage. So, it may be you're approaching the problem the wrong way.

Comment: I need to store additional data. I have to use an API that takes BIs and calls fns that i can override where i get them back. I could save that additional data somewhere else but that wont be OO. Extending BI was just the logical approach. until i ran into problems, like converting sys-created BIs into my extension. So i created a class that handles all that, it has copy-constructors, is cloneable and works like a charm. ……If u manually skip the security-concerns of the classloader *grrr* The principial problem is a bug: you can set properties ONLY if u created the BI with one special ctor!

Comment: … because the Hashmap (Hashtable properties) is not initialized. And you can set/get keys only after that. And you cant access the field, because it is package-visible, so u cant set it up yourself. … If I where Dagobert Duck, i'd simply buy Sun/Oracle and force sense into them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's how I would handle this:

```
public class MyBi extends BufferedImage
{
    private final BufferedImage realBufferedImage;

    public MyBi(BufferedImage bi)
    {
        super(0, 0, TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        realBufferedImage = bi;
    }

    // Add methods for managing your extra data

    // For every method in BufferedImage, override it like so:
    public void setData(Raster r)
    {
        realBufferedImage.setData(r);
    }
}
```

This is tedious to do by hand, but NetBeans has support for delegating.
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Insert</kbd>, select `Delegate Method...`, select `realBufferedImage` as the field in the left panel, check `BufferedImage` in the right panel and click `OK`. Instant delegation.

This should work because, although the fields of BufferedImage are at package scope, nothing else in the package accesses them.

Comment: I really had to reinvent the wheel just because getPropertyNames() was not implemented at all. My final solution to that problem was to file in a bug report and a feature request, and – after month of fruitless effort to talk some sense into the dev – just wrote a complete wrapper mimicing 1:1 all functions and adding the missing ones…

Answer (score 0):

You don't "add" to java.awt.Image. In your own package you extend the class and do as you please.

Sometimes, in open source projects, you can submit your class back to the project and have it become part of the project.

Comment: Not possible, see comment above

Comment: You might have mentioned in your question that you were depending on a package visible component of the public class.